# Cant send data to database and redirect isn't working

Tags: php, redirect

When you hit the "Post" button it should send the data to the database and redirect you to ?success=true but it will not redirect you or send the data to the DB.

This is suppose to do the redirecting and function calling:

```
if (empty($_POST['postBox']) === false && $_GET['success'] != true){
    sendPost();
    header("LOCATION: /offtopic.php?success=true");
    exit();
}
```

This is sendPost:

```
function sendPost()
{
    $postBox = '\'' . htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postBox'])) . '\'';
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `offtopicposts` (user_id, post, reported) VALUES ($user_id, $postBox, 0)") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

EDIT:
You can log in to [the off-topic page](http://www.bluewatercode.com) with the username: Test and password: Test123456789

Comment: what does it do instead? also, is error reporting turned on?

Comment: Error reporting is on, it is not redirecting or sending anything to the DB, you can see what its not doing if you go to bluewatercode.com/offtopic.php and loging in with username: Test Pass: Test123456789

Comment: just for fun, post the `print_r()` values of `$_POST` and `$_GET` could you?

Comment: The `$_POST['postBox']` is set and I can call that if the if statement is gone.

Answer (score 1):

put a return statement in function

```
function sendPost()
{
    $postBox = '\'' . htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postBox'])) . '\'';
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `offtopicposts` (user_id, post, reported) VALUES ($user_id, $postBox, 0)") or die(mysql_error());
   return;
}
```

Comment: @Carefree4 echo something after calling `sendPost();`if controls there then there in  problem with header() function .

Comment: Its echoing before and after the redirect.

Comment: @Carefree4 have you tried it with some known domain like `http://google.com` in header().

Answer (score 0):

Try this if condition

```
if (!empty($_POST['postBox']) && $_GET['success'] != 'true')
```

Comment: Nope, same thing... Wont send to the DB or redirect... The DB is working fine, I am able to log in and everything. Not giving me any errors or anything...

Comment: Just try to change with if(1) , it this gives success then something wrong with your if condition.

Comment: I tried your code, its working fine for me, just check there is any error or waring in server errorlog or access log

Comment: That's what i'm looking at now, "MaxRedirects option has been removed in favor of the global LimitInternalRecursion directive will be ignored"

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry... Because of the new background I was unable to see the error... In the DB something wasn't allowed to be null... So a quick fix and its working... Thank you all for the help!